# Cannot connect because of insecure connection (IE11 & Edge17)

Tags: https, security-certificate, internet-explorer, microsoft

Goodday,

I stumbled upon a problem with both IE and Edge, where the entire website cannot load because of an 'insecure' connection.

I checked and it uses TLS1.2 (which is a secure SSL, right?).

When I look up the problem I stumbled uppon a Microsoft post explaining from windows7 and higher (no broswer issue?) it cannot handle SSL2.0 or TLS1.2. The solution they provide is a clientside-only solution (see support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2851628).

Although I would be happy to uninstall IE and Edge, I assume others won't know of this problem and therefore will be unable to reach us.

So the question is; Is there a proper way to fix this? And is it fixable by me? Or is this a provider's problem?

I would love to hear your comments about this!